# Ford Ka 2006 revving on it's own

Tags: ford, ka

I've a we Ford Ka 1.3 2006. On first inspection no water in radiator, took two litres. Started it after few minutes. It started revving the nuts of it's self. I have not done any other tests as yet bar take plugs out, all ok. Car was only serviced last month and I've found the cause of low coolant. Before I go as far as to fix leak, what should I be looking for in the revving situation? Also, throttle sensor was replaced and along with the idle air; both new.

I work on bikes mainly. Just doing this for a friend and don't have diagnostic tool for Ford. What to do? Any ideas? First thought was head warped? Am I right before going down road of pressure testing? As Ka is not good nik not worth a rebuild if any other ideas? Be great for feed back.

Answer (score 1):

Check tension on throttle pedal as there a small amount of play before it engages if not loosen the throttle cable under the hood and make sure cable is moving freely it could have been tightened to much or cable could be stuck.